# Ending sentence with etc in parentheses

Tags: punctuation

I've seen prior discussions of ending a sentence with "etc." and I know there should only be one period.  But what if the "etc." comes inside parenthesis which then end the sentence, such as:

.....blah blah blah (blah, blah etc.).

That looks awkward to me.  Because the period inside the parentheses is used for the abbreviation I don't think it suffices to end the sentence with it; so I'm thinking:

.....blah blah blah (blah, blah etc.)

is incorrect.

I know I could always simply write-out *et cetera* but I'm wondering if there's an actual rule for this.

Thanks in advance.

---

Ok, so multiple people have marked this as asked and answered.  Could someone please post a link to that, because I can't find it.

@tchrist: unicorns???

---

Never mind.  Found the link in the right margin.  Thank you.

Comment: It's simpler to use etc rather than etc. in the first place.

Comment: Because ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎unicorns.